# Pyqtgraph multiple horizontal axes

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I would like to use pyqtgraph to plot optical spectra of some signal vs wavelength in nm. The harder part is that it would be useful to plot the energy of the corresponding wavelength along the top of the graph. See the bottom figure for an example.

My question is how to accomplish this in pyqtgraph. I've thought about trying to modify the two y-axis solution (such as [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/1PrA5VS4sy8)), but I don't think it's really appropriate. The axis should be linked, not free to move independently, so adding a new viewbox doesn't seem like the right path, unless it's to link everything.

I think I could do something by adding a new axisitem and connecting the appropriate resizing signals to force the new axis coordinates to work, but that feels rather dirty.

http://www.nature.com/nnano/journal/v10/n10/images/nnano.2015.178-f1.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick work around which somewhat works for my purposes. I figure I'll post it here in case others are curious and it may be helpful for them. It involves subclassing AxisItem and specifying tickStrings. It doesn't work ideally, as it maintains the same tick positions as the main bottom axis, but it should be at least give me an idea for what I'm looking at.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

class CustomAxis(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return ['{:.4f}'.format(1./i) for i in values]

pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: MultipleXAxes')
p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.setLabels(left='axis 1')


# Get rid of the item at the grid position where the top should be
p1.layout.removeItem(p1.getAxis('top'))
# make our own, setting the parent and orientation
caxis = CustomAxis(orientation='top', parent=p1)
caxis.setLabel('inverted')
caxis.linkToView(p1.vb)
# set the new one for internal plotitem
p1.axes['top']['item'] = caxis
# and add it to the layout
p1.layout.addItem(caxis, 1, 1)



p1.plot(np.arange(1, 7), [1,2,4,8,16,32])
#p2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(1./np.arange(1, 7), [1,2,4,8,16,32], pen='b'))

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Obviously, the return value should be replaced by whatever function relates the two axis.

Comment: I had a similiar problem but in my case it was also depending on the plot how the axis should be changed. I solved it in the following way, but it feels not correct. The link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545364/pyqtgraph-imageitems-new-axis-labels. Maybe you can help me?